# Efficient path for displaying customized video in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera

In Android, I need an efficient way of modifying the camera stream before displaying it on the screen.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676814/previewcallback-onpreviewframe-does-not-change-data) discusses a couple of ways of doing so and I was able to implement the first one:

1. Get frame buffer from onPreviewFrame
2. Convert frame to YUV
3. Modify frame
4. Convert modified frame to jpeg
5. Display frame to ImageView which was placed on SurfaceView used for the
   preview

That worked but brought down the 30 fps I was getting with a regular camera preview to 5 fps or so.  Converting frames back and forth from different image spaces is also power hungry, which I don't want.

Are there examples on how to get access to the raw frames directly and not have to go through so many conversions?  Is using OpenGL the right way of doing this?  It must be a very common thing to do but I can't find good examples.

Note: I'd rather avoid using the Camera2 APIs for backward compatibility sake.

Comment: What modifications are you attempting to perform? Some things are very straightforward with GLES manipulation, some are awkward. One example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg

Comment: I need to apply some proprietary signal processing chain (written in C) that must run on the CPU, not on the GPU.

Comment: If your code has to run on the CPU, then you can't use OpenGL ES (by definition, unless you're a huge fan of Mesa). You can use an ImageReader (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html) to get direct access to the YUV data from the Surface, avoiding the initial buffer copy and RGB conversion, but that requires API 19+.

Comment: Couldn't  OpenGL be used to write to memory that could then be accessed from the CPU?  Basically, I am looking for the least CPU intensive data flow allowing raw camera data to be modified before being displayed.

Comment: Earlier you said you've got code written in C that must run on the CPU, and your question indicated that it need to be in YUV. The ImageReader path gets you CPU access to the YUV data with very little overhead (it abstracts away the planar/semi-planar formatting and alignment offsets). Unless you can do processing on the GPU, you're not going to do much better. BTW, why do you convert the frame to JPEG? Are you storing it somewhere? That's going to cost you quite a bit.

Comment: My current (slow) code is in Java and relies heavily on APIs: first to convert the camera image into YUVImage, then to convert the YUVImage into jpeg (compressToJpeg), and then to convert the compressed stream to a bitmap needed for the image view. I use jpeg currently because I do not see Java APIs allowing to bypass the costly JPEG encoding. As I move to doing the image processing in C & more manually, I will drop the JPEG conversion but my current low frame rate makes me nervous that this won't be enough to get significantly higher frame rates, hence my original question.

Comment: In fact, reading more about ImageView, it seems that one way or another the representation, whether as a Bitmap or a Drawable, has to be in some compressed format (jpeg, png, etc.). So I am not even sure I can bypass the conversion to jpeg if I use an ImageView. Can I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient form of your CPU-based pipeline would look something like this:

1. Receive frames from the Camera on a Surface, rather than as `byte[]`.  With Camera2 you can send the frames directly to an [ImageReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html); that will get you CPU access to the raw YUV data from the Camera without copying it or converting it.  (I'm not sure how to rig this up with the old Camera API, as it wants either a SurfaceTexture or SurfaceHolder, and ImageReader doesn't provide those.  You can run the frames through a SurfaceTexture and get RGB values from `glReadPixels()`, but I don't know if that'll buy you anything.)
2. Perform your modifications on the YUV data.
3. Convert the YUV data to RGB.
4. Either convert the RGB data into a Bitmap or a GLES texture.  [glTexImage2D](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) will be more efficient, but OpenGL ES comes with a steep learning curve.  Most of the pieces you need are in Grafika (e.g. the [texture upload benchmark](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/TextureUploadActivity.java)) if you decide to go that route.
5. Render the image.  Depending on what you did in step #4, you'll either render the Bitmap through a Canvas on a [custom View](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html), or render the texture with GLES on a SurfaceView or TextureView.

I think the most significant speedup will be from eliminating the JPEG compression and uncompression, so you should probably start there.  Convert the output of your frame editor to a Bitmap and just draw it on the Canvas of a TextureView or custom View, rather than converting to JPEG and using ImageView.  If that doesn't get you the speedup you want, figure out what's slowing you down and work on that piece of the pipeline.

Comment: I am confused in part of your answer. Isn't a bitmap necessarily a compressed representation of an image (jpeg, png, etc.)? If so, doesn't step 4 "convert the RGB data into a Bitmap" lead to jpeg encoding (or some other compression) no matter what? Since I wrote this question, I tried going down the path of using OpenGL and have my camera stream to the display using a GLES texture, but I am not closer to being able to understanding how I can efficiently on the CPU, in Java or C using JNI, modify the yuv plane before previewing it. Some code illustrating this would be great! Thanks

Comment: No. android.graphics.Bitmap wraps an uncompressed bag of RGBA pixels. You can use `Bitmap#compress()` to write JPEG/PNG/WEBP, and use BitmapFactory to convert a compressed image to a Bitmap, but the Bitmap storage is not compressed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're restricted to the old camera API, then using a SurfaceTexture and doing your processing in a GPU shader may be most efficient.

This assumes whatever modifications you want to do can be expressed reasonably as a GL fragment shader, and that you're familiar enough with OpenGL to set up all the boilerplate necessary to render a single quadrilateral into a frame buffer, using the texture from a SurfaceTexture.

You can then read back the results with glReadPixels from the final rendering output, and save that as a JPEG.

Note that the shader will provide you with RGB data, not YUV, so if you really need YUV, you'll have to convert back to a YUV colorspace before processing.

If you can use camera2, as fadden says, ImageReader or Allocation (for Java/JNI-based processing or Renderscript, respectively) become options as well.

And if you're only using the JPEG to get to a Bitmap to place on an ImageView, and not because you want to save it, then again as fadden says you can skip the encode/decode step and draw to a view directly. For example, if using the Camera->SurfaceTexture->GL path, you can just use a GLSurfaceView as the output destination and render directly into a GLSurfaceView if that's all you need to do with the data.